# Why is it said that we can obtain a digital signature from a CA when all we obtain from the CA is a certificate?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, digital-signature, asymmetric

Several sites, like [this](https://www.instantssl.com/digital-signature) states that

> You can obtain a digital signature from a reputable certificate
> authority such as Sectigo

But digital signature is something you create using a piece of text and your private key using a signing algorithm. How can I obtain a digital signature from a CA? Shouldn't I just be receiving the **digital signing certificate** from the CA and creating the digital signature by myself?

Comment: Yes, and the link you provided says exactly that. The only confusing bit to that whole page appears to be that one sentence. Is there another place that says the same? I think it's just a typo and they meant to say "you can obtain a digital **certificate**" since the next line is talking about certificates.

Comment: I googled the phrase and it appears that several small companies have copy/pasted the same basic page for themselves. It's just a typo that people have been blindly copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo.

They meant to say "you can obtain a digital **certificate**" since the next line is talking about certificates. And the rest of the page sets up the correct understanding of how the process works.

I googled the quote you provided and it appears that several small companies have copy/pasted the same basic page for themselves. It's just a typo that people have been blindly copying.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bit oversimplified and mixed together here.

We need to distinguish a few things:

1. The CA issues a digital certificate with a **digital signature** to you
2. You can use the signed digital certificate to **sign other data** (depending on the certificate, that can be TLS handshakes, e-mail signatures and so on).

> You can obtain a digital signature from a reputable certificate authority such as Sectigo

What they mean here is that a certificate authority takes your certificate signing request (CSR), adds or removes certain fields from it, puts it into a slightly different format (a "to be signed certificate") and adds a **digital signature** to it, which makes it a valid, trusted X.509v3 certificate that you can use to sign other things.

> Shouldn't I just be receiving the digital signing certificate from the CA and creating the digital signature by myself?

Yes, this is exactly how it works.